# Creating sequence using adjacency matrix in Python

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, dependencies, adjacency-matrix

I am trying to create a sequence based on dependency matrix in Python. In order to do so, I am trying to use a adjacency matrix such that I can create a directed graph which will basically represent the sequence. For example,

```
  A B C D E
A 0 0 0 0 0
B 1 0 0 0 0
C 0 1 0 0 0
D 1 0 0 0 0
E 0 1 0 1 0
```

This would represent sequence ABCDE as B depends on A, C depends on B an so on. I am randomly creating this matrix, which is a lower triangular matrix. The problem I am having is once I randomly create a matrix, sometimes there is direct connection along with indirect connection between the row and column, which is a redundancy. For example, if the above matrix was slightly changed to the following matrix,

```
      A B C D E
    A 0 0 0 0 0
    B 1 0 0 0 0
    C 0 1 0 0 0
    D 0 0 1 0 0
    E 0 1 0 1 0
```

There would be redundancy as E is indirectly connected to B via C and directly connected to B as well. I want to remove the direct connection between E and B. I am having problem doing so. I tried using spanning tree but it does not work because I want to preserve the situation presented in top matrix (i.e. E is dependent on A indirectly via B and also has separate indirect dependency via D, which is valid) but correct the situation in second matrix (i.e. E is directly dependent on B and also indirectly dependent on B via D as well). Below is the code that I have so far.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv



n = 20
k = 0
rowNum = 5
colNum = 4
numValue = ((rowNum+1)/2)*colNum
m = (np.random.rand(n, n) * 2).astype(np.int)
matrix = np.tril(m, -1)
for (i,j), value in np.ndenumerate(matrix):
    for k in np.arange(0,len(matrix[i]), 1):
        if (matrix[i][j] == 1 and matrix[j][k] == 1):
            matrix[i][k] = 0
        else: continue
        if (i-j > colNum and i-j < numValue) or (i-j > (numValue+colNum)):
            matrix[i][j] = 0
        else:
            continue    
    if i <= j: 
        continue
    else:
        if np.sum(matrix[i] == 1) >= 4:
            matrix[i][j] = 0
        else:continue

names = [i for i in 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST']
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix, index=names, columns=names)
df.to_csv('df.csv', index=True, header=True, sep=',')
```

How to I include this condition in the code? Or do I need to have a completely different approach?